# Monitoring Chromium on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

I run Raspberries as Info screens, they show videos in chromium-browser. They happen to freeze from time to time, so I have a cronjob that does „pkill chrom*“ and restarts the browser every 10 Minutes.

Sometimes the whole Raspi freezes so bad, that even this approach fails. I know that Raspberries come with an hardware watchdog but I did not manage to configure this properly.

My next Idea: starting chromium with selenium and checking for „not responsible“ in the title every few minutes and restart the browser. This would be better then just stop and restart chromium every 10min, does it? I am not sure how much resources selenium needs.

If you have clever Ideas how to tackle this problem, please let me know.